# AWS HVM instance cost

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is HVM instances in AWS are free of cost? If yes then please let me know the details of that instance types and HVM AMI. I didnt find any help on internet. I only found that its charged per hour basis

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

only t2.micro instances qualifies for free-tier (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) wether the the AMI is HVM or PV type.
You're confused between virtualization mode and EC2 instance type.

---

read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html to understand that Amazon is using 2 virtualization modes

> Linux Amazon Machine Images use one of two types of virtualization:
>   paravirtual (PV) or hardware virtual machine (HVM). The main
>   difference between PV and HVM AMIs is the way in which they boot and
>   whether they can take advantage of special hardware extensions (CPU,
>   network, and storage) for better performance.

Amazon charges per instance type, see http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ to get a list of the latest instance types